# Can I access a class without an __init__? - Python

Tags: python, function, class

I want to be able to print "hello harry" from a module. This is my module (called test23):

```
class tool:

    def handle(self,name):
        self.name = "hello " + name
```

This is my script:

```
import test23

harry= test23.tool().handle(" harry")
print harry.name
```

I can't seem to print "hello harry" inside my script idle. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Does this code produce some sort of error or exception? Can you include that in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tool.handle()` doesn't return an object, so you need to store the object before you call the method:

```
import test23

harry = test23.tool()
harry.handle("harry")
print harry.name
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

`handle` doesn't return anything, so `harry` will be `NoneType`.
Do it in two times: first assign the instance, then call the method:

```
>>> class tool:
...   def hello(self,name):
...      self.name="hello "+name
...
>>> a=tool()
>>> a.hello('i')
>>> a.name
'hello i'
>>> b=tool().hello('b')
>>> b.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
>>> type(b)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will do it.

```
from test23 import tool

harry = tool()
harry.handle("harry")
print harry.name
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wanted to do is:

```
harry = test23.tool()  # Ok harry is a tool object
harry.handle(" harry") # Ok harry.name has been set to " harry"
print harry.name       # Ok print successfully "hello  harry"
```

But what you did is: `harry= test23.tool().handle(" harry")`

Let's look one pass at a time:

- `test23.tool()` : builds a new (temporary) `tool` object
- `test23.tool().handle(" harry")` : sets the attribute `name` of the temporary and returns... `None`!
- `harry= test23.tool().handle(" harry")` : sets the attribute name of a temporary `tool` object, set `harry` to the return value of the `handle` method which is `None` => same as `harry = None`

Alternatively, you should change `handle` to return the `tool` object:

class tool:

```
def handle(self,name):
    self.name = "hello " + name
    return self
```